# Error with path of my picture directory PYTHON

Tags: python, path, pygame, relative-path, directory-structure

I try to access to one of my pictures in one of my directories but i get an error each time. 
Actually, my folder is like that :

```
gamefolder:
    lib:
        main.py
        level.py
        othermodules.py
        ...
    data:
        Level1.png
        otherspictures.png
```

In the primary python file who is main.py, i wrote :

```
currentpath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) 
parentpath = os.path.dirname(currentpath) 
sys.path.append(os.path.join(parentpath, 'data'))
```

But I always get an error in one of my script : level.py called by main.py :

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open Level_1.png
```

The code in level.py is like that :

```
self.image = pygame.image.load('Level1.png').convert_alpha()
```

I'm not yet familiar with python path .. But it would be so nice if i can arrange that folder like that, which is very elegant !

Thanks to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
currentpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# or 
#currentpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

datadir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(currentpath), 'data')

self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(datadir, 'Level1.png')).convert_alpha()
```

The path `sys.argv[0]` can be *main.py* and its `dirname` is an empty string

**Updated**

As the manual of [`pygame`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load)

You should use `os.path.join()` for compatibility.

Comment: I also tried but i'm using IDLE (so __file__ is not working ) , and in an other IDE like pyscripter I get the same error couldn't open Level1.png ..
I checked with a print(currentpath) it's not empty .. I also checked in sys.path there is my data folder ...

Comment: Updated. But I don't understand the meaning that **file** is not working

Comment: It could work I think but I must add datadir like a variable in each function I called . It would not be elegant :/ Unless there's a way to call datadir without doing def ..(self,datadir)? Perhaps with a class called for example path and a path.datadir ?

Comment: Hum.. the instruction --file-- doesn't work in IDLE because it's an interactive python shell ;)

Comment: `sys.path.append` is used for `import` some modules.

Comment: I create a constant.py which contain that code and i did from constantes import * it works perfect ! Thanks @mskimm